# Unable to install new python libraries

Tags: python

I just came back from vacation and after getting a bunch of windows updates, I am no longer able to work with my python env. All the libraries in my virtual env have stopped to work and I kept receiving `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools`when trying to install them again.

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ build tools again and now it works for some of them(pandas for example). However, for most of libraries(Office365-REST-Python-Client as an example), I am getting this :

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography

  Failed building wheel for cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

BUT I do not have cryptography installed at this point. I have used it in one of my projects before and it seems like those leftovers are breaking something. However, I don't really know where to look for them. I have re-installed python(i have tried few versions as well) to a different location but the problem prevails. Problem occurs from Pycharm and command line.I am really confused so I would appreciate any advice!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Interesting problem statement. I would like to know how this gets resolved. Will follow along. Did you reinstall Pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to remove *all* Python versions and distributions.

Then re-install Python from `python.org`. You should probably use the "Windows x86-64 executable installer".

Download and install all Python modules you want as wheels (`.whl` extension). That way you shouldn't have to build anything yourself.